# Display image from firebase collection in Angular (Material)

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material

I recieve an image url from a firebase collection and want to display the picture in an angular app. Both are queried with the same code.

Why does this work:

```
<img matListAvatar src={{item.img}}>
```

But none of these do:

```
<img mat-card-image src={{item.img}}>
<img mat-card-image [src]=item.img>
<img src="{{item.img}}">
```

Comment: if the `image URL` is coming from firebase, you might need to check if it has been received 
`<img *ngIf="item.img" mat-card-image src="{{ item.img }}" >`

Comment: But why does the matListAvatar never fail? It can show 200 images in a list, but the mat-card-image either doesn't show anything or GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found). Your recommendation shows nothing and then I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED 200.

Comment: We'll need more code here. Can you also include where `item` is being set and looped over?